# QGIS Zoom full problem on WMS layer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, zoom

I have a project in QGIS with an online OSM WMS layer and some other vector layers. When I click on zoom full, it zoom outs so that the whole world is shown through OSM WMS layer. Is there an option to make it zoom to a predefined extent, or ignores the WMS layer?

Comment: The OSM layer is not a WMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to edit the full extent in the project properties?

[image]